# Disabling bound parameters in SQLAlchemy Execute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `sqlalchemy-snowflake` to execute a query which includes JSON:

```py
%sql select parse_json('{"fruit":"banana"}'):fruit
```

`:fruit` is valid Snowflake SQL, [see here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_path).

Executing this statement provides this error:

```
(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'fruit'
[SQL: select parse_json('{"fruit":"banana"}')%(fruit)s]
```

SQLAlchemy mistakes `:fruit` for a bound parameter. How might I execute this query with **bound parameters disabled** / ignoring instances of `:x`?

The flow of my code makes escaping the colon with `\` not an option.

I would prefer an alternative to `connection.execute()` which avoids parsing of bound parameters. I have used `connection.exec_driver_sql()` but I still require the other compilation/transpilation/rollback steps that `.exec_driver_sql()` misses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The flow of my code makes escaping the colon with `\` not an option."? Why can't you do this?

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10922